# Find the the total number of 1's in binary form for a group number's in a list in python 3

Tags: list, binary, python-3.5

I want to count total number of '1's in binary format of a number which is in a list.

```
z = ['0b111000','0b1000011'] # z is a list 
d = z.count('1')
print(d)
```

The  output is 0.

Whereas the required output should be in the form of [3,3]

which is number of ones in every element that Z is containing :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is :

```
z=['0b111000','0b1000011']
finalData = []
for word in z:
    finalData.append(word.count('1'))
print(finalData)
```

The problem with your code was you were trying to use count() method on list type and it is used for string. You first need to get the string from the list and then use count() method on it.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
z = ['0b111000','0b1000011'] 
d = z.count('1')
```

This attempts to find the number of times the string `'1'` is in `z`. This obviously returns `0` since `z` contains `'0b111000'` and `'0b1000011'`.

You should iterate over every string in `z` and count the numbers of `'1'` in every string:

```
z = ['0b111000','0b1000011']
output = [string.count('1') for string in z]
print(output)
#  [3, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

list.count(x) will count the number of occurrences such that it only counts the element if it is equal to x.

Use list comprehension to loop through each string and *then* count the number of 1s. Such as:

```
z = ['0b111000','0b1000011'] 
d = [x.count("1") for x in z]
print(d)
```

This will output:

> [3, 3]